# Which packages or functions can I use in R to plot 3D data like this?

Tags: r, visualization

There're many data points, each of which is associated with two coordinates and a numeral value, or three coordinates. And I wish it is coloured.
I checked packages "scatterplot3d" and "plot3D" but I couldn't find one like the example I give. It is like it has a fitting surface.

My data is basically like the following. In this way I think this kind of plot is gonna be perfectly suitble for this data:

```
    ki,kt,Top10AverageF1Score
    360,41,0.09371256716549396
    324,41,0.09539634212851525
    360,123,0.09473510831594467
    36,164,0.09773486852645874
    ...
```

But I also may have one more additional variable, which makes it like:

```
    NeighborhoodSize,ki,kt,Top10AverageF1Score
    10,360,41,0.09371256716549396
    15,324,41,0.09539634212851525
    15,360,123,0.09473510831594467
    20,36,164,0.09773486852645874
    ...
```

**Do you also have any good idea for visualizing the second case? What kind of plot and which packages and functions, etc.**
[image]

Comment: Be clearer about the structure of your data. Is it already gridded? Or do you need to interpolate it to a grid first? Because that's a whole other big question. Then (once you have a grid) can we talk about 3d graphics. Show us a chunk of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `wireframe` function from the `lattice` package:

```
library("lattice")
wireframe(volcano[1:30, 1:30], shade=TRUE, zlab="")
```

[image: wireframe plot example]

Comment: That is just.. fantastic!